# Persistence Layer without the use of a framework

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have built a small J2EE message board application. The persistence tier uses JPA (hibernate) to handle the relational/object mapping and data storage. I understand that not all applications use a JPA type framework for modeling their data, and some use a more jdbc based approach that is more manual, interacting directly with the tables.

What I am trying to do is recreate my persistence logic without using JPA, just to learn how the implementation looks.

I've already recreated simple operations like retreiving all User ID's, and now, I am trying to work on the getUserById() method, which takes in a User ID, and returns a User object

I basically have 3 classes in play here:

```
-User(has attributes: id,username,password,list<post>,list<thread>started)
-Thread(has attributes: id,title,list<post>, date,category,author(user),locked)
-Post(has attributes: id,author(user),date,content,thread(that it belongs to)
```

Each of these objects are represented by a table in the database:

```
USER (ID,USERNAME,PASSWORD)
THREAD(ID,AUTHOR_ID,TITLE,START_DATE,CATEGORY,LOCKED)
POSTS(ID,AUTHOR_ID,PUBLISH_DATE,CONTENT,THREAD_ID)
```

I though it would be simple to build up a User object by querying the 3 tables, but what I'm finding is when I get to building up the list of threads that the user has started, I have to build those thread objects, which means going off and finding who their authors are, what posts they've made, etc, and it's turning into a mess, so I'm pretty sure I'm making it harder than it has to be.

The hibernate solution works perfectly since it handles the joins and the actual table level queries, but for shops that don't use jpa, is it that difficult to recreate these complex objects with pure sql, especially when the objects have references to each other, like the thread and the post objects?

I'm assuming I am missing something.

I can get the id,username,password from a single query, thats easy. 
I can get all of the users posts with a single query, but when it comes to creating that list of threads object, that's where it gets weird.

Answer (score 0):

Just enable "show_sql" from Hibernate and copy and paste the generated SQL queries `;)`.

Pseudocode for the loop part:

```
User user = SELECT_USER_FROM_DB;
List<Thread> threads = SELECT_THREAD_FROM_DB_WHERE_AUTHOR_ID_EQUALS_USER_ID;
user.threads = threads;
for(Thread thread : threads) {
    List<Post> posts = SELECT_POST_FROM_DB_WHERE_THREAD_ID_EQUALS_THREAD_ID;
    thread.posts = posts;
}
List<Post> posts = SELECT_POST_FROM_DB_WHERE_AUTHOR_ID_EQUALS_USER_ID;
user.posts = posts;
for(Post post : user.posts) {
    Thread thread = SELECT_THREAD_FROM_DB_WHERE_THREAD_ID_EQUALS_POST_THREAD_ID;
    post.thread = thread;
}
```

This will get all threads from the user. And for each of those threads, it will get all posts. Additionally it will get all posts made by this user. And at last, it will fetch all Threads for all user posts.

Comment: Well, the sql isn't the tough part, it's manually recreating a User object. I can get the id,username,password from a single query, thats easy. I can get all of the users posts with a single query, but when it comes to creating that list of threads object, that's where it gets weird.

Comment: You must create create the `Thread` objects in a loop and then save them in a `java.util.Collection` within your `User` object. Building an object from SQL is always the same, doesn't matter if it's a `User` object or a `Thread` object. Maybe you could also have a look at some NoSQL solution, there you could store all those one-to-many relations within a single document. And retrieve it without joining data.

Comment: The query for the threads doesn't return a List of thread objects, it's manual.

Comment: What do you mean by "manual" ? If you're using SQL, you can fetch a list from DB. Just create a query like `SELECT * FROM Thread WHERE Thread.id IN (?)`

Comment: What would that look like? Right now I am executing the query using Statements, and the return value is a ResultSet Object that I iterate over and manually pull column values using rs.getString("col_name")

Comment: Fetching a single user (with id=5) is `SELECT * FROM User WHERE User.id = 5`. Fetching all threads of a user (with id=5) is: `SELECT * FROM Thread WHERE Thread.author_id = 5`. Fetching all Threads for a List of Posts (with ids = [ 13, 42, 23 ]) is `SELECT * FROM Thread WHERE Thread.id IN (13,42,23)`. For each of those objects, you got to manually convert those to your Java objects using something like `rs.getString(...)`.